# Looking to build a low powered linux based firewall

Tags: distribution-choice, firewall

I am looking to build a low powered linux based firewall. I need a reliable piece of hardware that has two (2) LAN inputs and a built in wifi. Fanless and low power system. any recommendations? Any recomendations on software? I was looking at IPcop.

Comment: OpenWRT on dedicated router hardware?

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of options here.

#### 1. Get a low cost router switch and install either [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) or [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) firmware

- [list of supported devices for OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start)
- [Tomato Firmware/Supported Devices](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Tomato_Firmware/Supported_Devices)

It's difficult to recommend any particular piece of hardware, I'd look through the software projects and find one that looks like it has the feature set you're looking for and then find hardware that supports it.

**NOTE:** There are other projects besides these 2. See these wikipedia articles:

- [List of wireless router firmware projects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wireless_router_firmware_projects)
- [List of router or firewall distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_or_firewall_distributions)

#### 2. Setup a basic box with pfSense

[pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) is free, open source customized distribution of FreeBSD tailored for use as a firewall and router. In addition to being a powerful, flexible firewalling and routing platform, it includes a long list of related features and a package system allowing further expandability without adding bloat and potential security vulnerabilities to the base distribution.

- There's a good [overview of common deployment](http://www.pfsense.org/index.php@option=com_content&task=view&id=71&Itemid=81.html) configurations
- [Information on possible hardware devices](http://www.pfsense.org/index.php@option=com_content&task=category&sectionid=9&id=28&Itemid=47.html)

#### 3. [IPCop](http://www.ipcop.org/)

You've already mentioned this one, but I'm putting it here just to detail more information about it.

- [IPCop Hardware Compatibility List](http://www.rkaehler.de/ipcop/hcl.html)

#### 4. Others

- [M0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/)
- [Smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.org/)
- [ClearOS](http://www.clearfoundation.com/Software/overview.html)
- [Ebox Platform](http://www.ebox-platform.com/)

Check out [this review](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/applications/7-of-the-best-linux-firewalls-697177/1) for more details on the above mentioned Firewall applications.

Comment: One tip for picking a router for OpenWRT (which is what I recommend).  Check out the instructions for emergency reflashing.  If you're building custom images, you _will_ eventually install one that won't boot.  Some routers make it easy to reflash from the bootloader, some make it difficult, and some can't be fixed at all if you brick them.